# mail sending issue in laravel 5.4

Tags: email, sendmail, linux-mint, laravel-5.4

I am trying to send an email using laravel 5.4. here is my **.env**

```
 MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=username@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

here is my **HomeController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Mail;
use App\Mail\MyTestMail;

class HomeController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Send My Test Mail Example
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function myTestMail()
    {
        //echo 'hello';
        $myEmail = 'example@gmail.com';
        Mail::to($myEmail)->send(new MyTestMail());


        dd("Mail Send Successfully");
    }

}
```

But i got an error like

> Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383:
>   Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8
>   Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8
>   https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials r67sm38867592pfb.125
>   - gsmtp "

```
at Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_assertResponseCode('535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials r67sm38867592pfb.125 - gsmtp ', array(250)) in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 281
at Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->executeCommand('RSET ', array(250), array()) in EsmtpTransport.php line 270
at Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport->executeCommand('RSET ', array(250)) in XOAuth2Authenticator.php line 55
at Swift_Transport_Esmtp_Auth_XOAuth2Authenticator->authenticate(object(Swift_SmtpTransport), 'username@gmail.com', 'password') in AuthHandler.php line 176
at Swift_Transport_Esmtp_AuthHandler->afterEhlo(object(Swift_SmtpTransport)) in EsmtpTransport.php line 332
```

Then i changed to my .env file to

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=username2@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password2
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

then i restart apache2.But still the same error with previous username and password.i don't know why this happens?please help me.

Comment: i have about the same problem with L5.4 on php7. but I tried same setting in local php54 able to send out. I'm trying hard to figure out the reason caused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google now doesn't accept login from less secure apps

You need to authorise the external application use of Gmail.

Follow the next steps and authorise to make it:

> First, go to [your Google Account Management page](https://myaccount.google.com/security)
>
> Under the Security options, click Edit link of Authorising
>   applications & sites

or

You can allow less secure apps from your settings in Gmail, go to:

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

and set 'Access for less secure apps' to "Enabled"

Hope it helps you.